# How to exclude ASP.NET web site code-behind files from compile?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, code-behind

I am refactoring a stack of ASP.NET pages.  I'd like to compile and test the ones I've completed.  However, Visual Studio won't let me run the Web Site with compile errors on the non-refactored pages.  How can I temporarily exclude them without removing them from the project itself?  Can you do so through configuration of some sort?

Comment: Your checked the wrong answer. Look @notytony's one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Visual studio 2010 or later, you can achieve the functionality in two ways.

1)Right click the file, select '**Exclude From Project**'

2)Right click the file, select '**Properties**' --> select '**Configuration Properties**' --> select '**General**' --> choose '**Yes**' from drop down menu for option '**Excluded From Build**'

Comment: Any shortcuts for exclude from build?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the file(s) and select "Exclude from project".

Comment: Doing this the files are removed from the project, I don't know why @Larsenal marked this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two projects and copy over the completed ones to the new project as they are refactored, then build the new project.