# Visual studio exclude folders from rebuild

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, compilation

I'm building an addon ASP.net set of pages ontop of an old classic ASP system.

The new pages are in the folder `newversion/` this is the only folder I need rebuilding when I make changes, at the moment it attempts to build the entire site which results in a lot of errors.

Can you exclude all other folders from the build configuration?

**Edit** Please note, the other pages are still going to be edited (all the classic ASP ones) so exlcuding them from project etc really doesn't help

**Edit 2**  Here's a screen shot from VS
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the files you like to exclude in the solution explorer
2. Press <kbd>F4</kbd>\<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open properties window.
3. Change **Build Action** property to **Nnoe**.

[image]

Comment: This is VS2008, the only properties showing are filename and fullpath

Comment: @Tom: The screen capture I've add taken from VS2008

Comment: Thanks for your help HuBeZa I've uploaded a screenshot from original question, I don't seem to have these options.  The project was opened via the "file > open website", is this why?

Comment: You are correct. This solution doesn't work on websites. Try mark the file as hidden as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219381/how-to-exclude-files-from-visual-studio-compile/4346613#4346613)

Comment: Thanks, will this affect other people working on the project though if they need to edit those hidden folders?

Comment: You mean other people that use it through some kind of source control? I recommend trial and error