# Excluding filters/folders from a Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've searched up and down and found a number of good solutions to excluding individual files from being compiled in a Visual Studio 2013 project...

[How to exclude files from Visual Studio compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219381/how-to-exclude-files-from-visual-studio-compile)

But isn't it possible to - at least temporarily - exclude an entire folder/filter? I've found no clues or hints as to how to accomplish this.

I figure there must at least be a way for me to do with in either in the .vcxproj or .vcxproj.filters file. Ideally I would like either temporarily comment out some lines, or add a few lines where necessary (indicating which filters/folders to exclude) and *not* have to do this for every single file.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Me