# How do I exclude files and folders from the build in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In some older versions you could easily [right click on the folders and exclude from build.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219381/how-to-exclude-files-from-visual-studio-compile)

This function seems to be gone in VS 2017 Community. How do I achieve the same?

Update: it seems the function is not completely gone, it's possible to exclude files from the project when the Solution Explorer is not in folder view. This is not a solution anyway, since I need to exclude a whole folder that's got plenty of files, excluding them one by one is not at all a practical solution. It's something I can do in an emergency scenario, but not a reliable way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Press right-click on the file you want to exclude, and click on properties. In `General->Excluded from build`, select Yes.

Comment: There is no "properties" option if I right click the file.

Comment: @EärendilBaggins Where are you clicking? You should click on the file in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Was actually looking for a way to exclude a file from cleanup/rebuild. While this answer couldn't help in my case (intentionally), I still learned a new feature of VS that could come in handy in other cases. I found it as described by machine_1. Hence, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not be what you are looking for, but since "Publish Web App" is under the build tab, it fits and may help someone else.

In your "App_Data" folder there should be a "PublishProfiles" folder with a [projectname].pubxml file in it.

Add:

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
  foldername;otherfoldername
</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

This will exclude listed folders from being published.

Expanding on that, for files:

```
<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
   gulpfile.js;PrecompiledApp.config
</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned this option is gone from more recent versions of VS. This is why I wrote this extension working in VS2013 and later:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamWulkiewicz.ExcludeFromBuild