# Fody System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: xamarin.forms, out-of-memory, fody, fody-propertychanged

I have a Xamarin Forms project where I use PropertyChanged.Fody.

I have update at the version 3.2.8 and this error is trigger when I try to compile the PCL project.

I'm on Visual Studio 16.6.0 on Windows.

How can I solve this?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Fody: An unhandled exception occurred:
Exception:
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
Type:
System.OutOfMemoryException
StackTrace:
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ByteBuffer.Grow(Int32 desired) in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil.PE\ByteBuffer.cs:line 328
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ByteBuffer.WriteBytes(Byte[] bytes) in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil.PE\ByteBuffer.cs:line 274
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddResources() in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil\AssemblyWriter.cs:line 1181
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildModule() in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil\AssemblyWriter.cs:line 1031
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildMetadata() in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil\AssemblyWriter.cs:line 1006
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.<>c.<BuildMetadata>b__2_0(MetadataBuilder builder, MetadataReader _) in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil\AssemblyWriter.cs:line 144
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet](TItem item, Func`3 read) in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil\ModuleDefinition.cs:line 947
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.BuildMetadata(ModuleDefinition module, MetadataBuilder metadata) in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil\AssemblyWriter.cs:line 143
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.Write(ModuleDefinition module, Disposable`1 stream, WriterParameters parameters) in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil\AssemblyWriter.cs:line 119
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModule(ModuleDefinition module, Disposable`1 stream, WriterParameters parameters) in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil\AssemblyWriter.cs:line 78
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters) in C:\Code\Fody\cecil\Mono.Cecil\ModuleDefinition.cs:line 1136
   at InnerWeaver.WriteModule() in C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\ModuleWriter.cs:line 19
   at InnerWeaver.Execute() in C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 114
Source:
Mono.Cecil
TargetSite:
Void Grow(Int32)
    SgatOffline     1
```

Comment: EDIT: I found the problem. Inside the application there is a test DB that is 1.7gb. When I remove it the app compile. But how can I tell to Fody to ignore that database's file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I tell to Fody to ignore that database's file?

To exclude a file from Visual Studio compile, try the following tips.

1.Set the **Build Action**  to None for the file you want excluded.

2.Right click on the folder and choose **Exclude from Project**.

Refer to: [How to exclude files from Visual Studio compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219381/how-to-exclude-files-from-visual-studio-compile)